# Методы JavaScript

Tags: javascript

В коде ниже массивы должны возвращать значения из массива values, но из-за ошибки в терминал выдает, что ошибка указывает на то, что один из объектов, для которых вызывается ".filter", не определен. Как исправить?

```
class Numbers {
        #values;
        #threshold;

        constructor(threshold, values) {
            this.#values = values;
            this.#threshold = threshold;
        }

        // Возвращает все значения из массива values, которые больше, чем значение переменной threshold
        getGreaterThanThreshold() {
            return this.values.filter(function (v) {
                return v > this.threshold;
            })
        };

        // возвращает все значения из массива values, которые меньше, чем значение переменной threshold 
        getLessThanThreshold() {
            return this.values.filter(function (v) {
                return v < this.threshold;
            })
        }
    };

    let numbers = new Numbers(50, [10, 20, 23, 11, 5, 6, 90, 33, 45, 67]);
    let gt = numbers.getGreaterThanThreshold();
    let lt = numbers.getLessThanThreshold();

    console.log(gt);
    console.log(lt);
```

Comment: У вас существует только `this.#values` и `this.#threshold`, а никаких `this.values` и `this.threshold` не существует

Comment: И добавлю на будущее, если какой либо метод не определен, значит у вас либо не установлено значение переменной, либо кастомный прототип, в котором нет этого метода, все это можно выяснить банальным законсоливанием переменной.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переменные this.#threshold и `this.threshold` разные. Внутри `filter` переменная `this.threshold` не видна..

```js
class Numbers {
        #values;
        #threshold;

        constructor(threshold, values) {
            this.values = values;
            this.threshold = threshold;
        }

        // Возвращает все значения из массива values, которые больше, чем значение переменной threshold
        getGreaterThanThreshold() {
          let thr = this.threshold;
            return this.values.filter(function (v) {
                return v > thr
            })
        };

        // возвращает все значения из массива values, которые меньше, чем значение переменной threshold 
        getLessThanThreshold() {
          let thr = this.threshold;
            return this.values.filter(function (v) {
                return v < thr;
            })
        }
    };

    let numbers = new Numbers(50, [10, 20, 23, 11, 5, 6, 90, 33, 45, 67]);
    
    let gt = numbers.getGreaterThanThreshold();
    let lt = numbers.getLessThanThreshold();

    console.log(gt);
    console.log(lt);
```